# Nuxt no page render on / but it does render on /index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my freshly created **nuxt** project, there seems to be something weird happening. Whenever i go to the root of the project e.g: `localhost:3000` there seems to be no render. But when i go to e.g: `localhost:3000/index` it does render the correct `index.vue` file.

Project structure is:

```
components\
-Hero.vue

layouts\
-default.vue
-error.vue

pages\
-index.vue
-About.vue
-Contact.vue
```

Index.vue contains

```
<template>
  <main>
    <Hero />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

default.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MainHeader />
    <Nuxt />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>


<style lang="scss">
@import "../assets/scss/main.scss";

</style>
```

My goal is to make it render the `index.vue` file, hope anyone can help me out

Comment: Hi! Can you show your package.json file to check versions? (It is not necessary but can u try to set name and layout properties to index.vue page and test again?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using App.vue: Try to use `<NuxtPage />`

Check Here  [Nuxt Pages](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages/)